# box-sizing using it before & after including margin and padding

Tags: html, css

Hello I have the following code which I would like to know if i'm doing it right and using it the right way or they should be split into separate classes. Please explain why I did it wrong and what else I should use as default for html tag and *, and should I use like html, body or only html?

```
*,  *:before, *:after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Same goes for this one:

```
html {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

Comment: Technically `box-sizing(border-box)` should be `box-sizing: border-box;` But generally it's hard to say what's wrong because it depends on your needs.

Comment: sorry i'm a little tired i have a mixin that makes the setup and i forgot to write it in the correct way here. :-( i apologize :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be [`box-sizing:border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

> Formal syntax: content-box | padding-box | border-box

It's also worth noting that you should use the `-moz` prefixed version for support in current versions of FF. Fortunately, future versions [(FF 29+) will support the property](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing) without a prefix.

```
*,  *:before, *:after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```